# Windows CMD: DIR *1* lists something else

Tags: vb.net, cmd, directory

I am making an app in **Visual Basic 2010** named *File Searcher*.
What it basically does is that it takes a path and a search query from the user and executes the Windows Command Line `DIR` command. My `Function` is as follows:

```
Public Function GetFiles(Path$, SearchQuery$, Attributes$, SearchSubFolders As Boolean) As String()
    If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(Path) Then Return {} : Exit Function
    If Not Path.EndsWith("\") Then Path &= "\"
    SearchQuery = If(Not SearchQuery.StartsWith("*") And Not SearchQuery.StartsWith("?"), "*", "") & SearchQuery
    SearchQuery = SearchQuery & If(Not SearchQuery.EndsWith("*") And Not SearchQuery.EndsWith("?"), "*", "")
    Dim CMDProcess As New Process()
    Dim CMDProcessInfo As New ProcessStartInfo()
    Dim OutputFilePath$ = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetTempFileName
    With CMDProcessInfo
        .FileName = "CMD.EXE"
        .Arguments = "/C DIR " & Attributes & " /B" & If(SearchSubFolders, " /S", "") & " """ & SearchQuery & """>""" & OutputFilePath & """"
        .WorkingDirectory = Path
        .CreateNoWindow = True
        .UseShellExecute = False
        .RedirectStandardError = True
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
    End With
    With CMDProcess
        .EnableRaisingEvents = True
        .StartInfo = CMDProcessInfo
        .Start()
    End With
    CMDProcess.WaitForExit()
    Dim Final() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(OutputFilePath)
    For Each Item$ In Final
        If Not Item.StartsWith(Path) Then Item = Path & Item
    Next
    Return Final
End Function
```

Now that is all fine. But the thing is that when I give **`*1*`** as the search query, such as `DIR /A /B /S *1*`, it gives a totally different thing.
Output of `DIR`:

```
Volume in drive C is Windows 10
Volume Serial Number is 541B-FF75

Directory of C:\Users\sreen\Desktop\All HTML files

07/Dec/16  09:11 PM    <DIR>          .
07/Dec/16  09:11 PM    <DIR>          ..
27/Feb/16  06:04 PM            12,106 5 Desert plants in UAE.html
07/Feb/15  06:25 PM               762 5 Populated countries.html
27/Aug/16  11:02 PM             1,933 Abbreviations.html
27/Sep/16  09:31 PM               880 About me.html
27/Feb/16  06:17 PM            20,396 Akbar - Birbal Stories.html
12/Apr/15  07:43 PM             2,288 Arabic letters.html
24/Oct/15  10:00 PM             1,445 Awesomest info.html
06/May/16  08:13 PM             1,607 BackupCodes.html
29/Nov/16  11:26 PM             1,776 Book.html
30/Nov/16  04:07 PM             3,893 Border customizer.html
30/Nov/16  04:08 PM             1,063 ButtonBass Chrome Piano.html
30/Nov/16  04:08 PM               377 ButtonBeats paino player.html
30/Nov/16  04:09 PM            15,497 Chr() Values.html
30/Nov/16  04:11 PM         5,808,642 ChrW() Values.html
30/Nov/16  04:11 PM               148 Climatic regions.html
03/Dec/16  02:44 PM             7,530 Code Editor.HTML
07/Aug/16  09:41 AM    <DIR>          Codes
11/Oct/16  03:38 PM             1,547 Command Line Emulator commands.txt
11/Oct/16  11:48 PM            19,630 Command Line Emulator.html
03/Dec/15  11:50 PM             4,379 Computer tips and tricks.html
29/Nov/16  11:19 PM             9,222 Contacts.html
23/Feb/15  04:12 PM             2,651 cookie_test.html
27/Sep/15  11:32 PM               672 Countries and their capitals.html
27/Sep/16  09:36 PM               836 Create custom HTML tag.html
05/Sep/15  04:17 PM             1,018 CSS Scrollbar.html
05/Mar/15  07:23 PM             1,785 Custom NumericUpDown.html
02/Apr/15  08:42 PM               396 Database registers.html
09/Aug/15  12:31 PM             3,912 Date and Time fillup.html
18/Jun/15  04:08 PM               452 Definitions.html
01/Oct/16  01:12 PM             3,487 dial.html
08/May/15  11:00 AM           993,891 Do not delete.html
24/Nov/16  06:37 PM               750 Double Spinner.html
01/Oct/16  02:07 PM             7,813 English - Book review.html
28/Feb/15  02:13 PM            11,990 Excel.html
03/Nov/16  05:54 PM             1,419 Funniest thing ever.html
05/Mar/15  03:42 PM             1,821 General Contacts.html
25/Jan/15  06:27 PM             1,620 Google Search.html
29/Jan/15  10:31 PM               308 google.html
12/Aug/15  07:23 PM           108,798 GoogleURLs.html
15/Nov/16  12:26 AM             4,206 Grade 7 FA-3 Arabic Words.HTML
15/Mar/15  12:55 PM               239 gradient.html
05/Mar/15  03:15 PM                36 Hello.html
20/Apr/15  04:31 PM             2,348 HTML KNOWN CODES.html
15/Jan/16  02:02 PM               840 HTML Property Retriever bookmarks.html
01/Oct/16  02:50 PM             9,218 Image clue guessing.html
21/Nov/15  11:26 AM             3,622 Indian state names and their capitals.html
22/Jun/14  08:00 PM               137 Internet Explorer InPrivate Icon.htm
22/Apr/16  08:13 PM             1,831 JavaScript Executer.html
22/Jun/15  04:24 PM            21,367 Keyboard Tester.html
18/Dec/14  12:41 PM               440 Lines.html
20/Apr/15  03:41 PM             2,692 List of fonts.html
25/Dec/14  12:26 PM             1,467 LOCATION.html
28/Jun/15  12:44 PM             2,978 Mathematics tips and tricks.html
01/Oct/16  03:15 PM            11,274 Maths project.html
01/Oct/16  03:16 PM             2,074 Menu Bar Top.html
01/Oct/16  03:21 PM             7,549 MIDI Voice list.html
20/May/14  07:40 PM             2,755 NAME and details.html
13/Oct/16  03:07 PM               364 Operating System.html
22/Feb/15  08:15 PM               538 Picture Linking.html
01/Oct/16  03:35 PM             1,364 POPUP.html
20/Apr/15  04:47 PM             1,477 Questions.html
07/Aug/16  09:41 AM    <DIR>          RGB (html)
25/Feb/15  09:33 PM             3,851 RGB to Hex converter.html
22/Jun/15  05:38 PM             2,301 Riddles.html
04/Jun/15  12:30 AM            13,958 S.St Project.html
27/May/14  04:24 PM             1,463 S.St.html
01/Oct/16  03:38 PM             1,402 School friends' contact numbers.html
07/Aug/14  11:49 AM               491 Select.html
02/Sep/15  06:07 PM             6,195 SUSRI links.html
24/Nov/16  09:16 PM             4,297 Teachers.html
26/Oct/15  10:51 PM               760 TEMP folders.html
07/Aug/16  09:41 AM    <DIR>          Testers, editors and simulators
25/Nov/16  12:40 PM             6,636 TimeTable.html
17/Aug/15  03:59 PM               446 ToSearch.html
29/Oct/16  01:50 PM            11,801 Ubuntu Keyboard Shortcuts.HTML
17/Aug/15  04:11 PM             4,338 Unusual characters.html
24/Nov/16  09:17 PM               956 Vanuvampet House TV Channels.html
05/Jan/15  05:56 PM               456 WEB-BROWSER TITLE TESTER (for designers).html
26/May/15  12:16 PM           172,480 Webpage not available.html
07/Feb/15  06:15 PM               727 What can I do now[sym question].html
21/Oct/16  08:23 PM             2,347 WhatsApp Formatting Converter.html
27/Jul/15  11:46 AM             1,484 Window.html
27/Nov/16  11:25 PM    <DIR>          Windows XP Style
25/Nov/16  01:07 PM            17,361 X 'n' O.SHTML
              80 File(s)      7,391,306 bytes
               6 Dir(s)  664,738,684,928 bytes free
```

Output of `DIR *1*`:

```
Volume in drive C is Windows 10
Volume Serial Number is 541B-FF75

Directory of C:\Users\sreen\Desktop\All HTML files

27/Feb/16  06:04 PM            12,106 5 Desert plants in UAE.html
07/Feb/15  06:25 PM               762 5 Populated countries.html
27/Aug/16  11:02 PM             1,933 Abbreviations.html
27/Sep/16  09:31 PM               880 About me.html
27/Feb/16  06:17 PM            20,396 Akbar - Birbal Stories.html
12/Apr/15  07:43 PM             2,288 Arabic letters.html
24/Oct/15  10:00 PM             1,445 Awesomest info.html
06/May/16  08:13 PM             1,607 BackupCodes.html
29/Nov/16  11:26 PM             1,776 Book.html
30/Nov/16  04:07 PM             3,893 Border customizer.html
30/Nov/16  04:08 PM             1,063 ButtonBass Chrome Piano.html
30/Nov/16  04:09 PM            15,497 Chr() Values.html
30/Nov/16  04:11 PM         5,808,642 ChrW() Values.html
30/Nov/16  04:11 PM               148 Climatic regions.html
03/Dec/16  02:44 PM             7,530 Code Editor.HTML
11/Oct/16  11:48 PM            19,630 Command Line Emulator.html
11/Oct/16  03:38 PM             1,547 Command Line Emulator commands.txt
03/Dec/15  11:50 PM             4,379 Computer tips and tricks.html
29/Nov/16  11:19 PM             9,222 Contacts.html
23/Feb/15  04:12 PM             2,651 cookie_test.html
27/Sep/15  11:32 PM               672 Countries and their capitals.html
27/Sep/16  09:36 PM               836 Create custom HTML tag.html
05/Sep/15  04:17 PM             1,018 CSS Scrollbar.html
05/Mar/15  07:23 PM             1,785 Custom NumericUpDown.html
02/Apr/15  08:42 PM               396 Database registers.html
09/Aug/15  12:31 PM             3,912 Date and Time fillup.html
18/Jun/15  04:08 PM               452 Definitions.html
01/Oct/16  01:12 PM             3,487 dial.html
08/May/15  11:00 AM           993,891 Do not delete.html
24/Nov/16  06:37 PM               750 Double Spinner.html
01/Oct/16  02:07 PM             7,813 English - Book review.html
28/Feb/15  02:13 PM            11,990 Excel.html
03/Nov/16  05:54 PM             1,419 Funniest thing ever.html
05/Mar/15  03:42 PM             1,821 General Contacts.html
25/Jan/15  06:27 PM             1,620 Google Search.html
15/Nov/16  12:26 AM             4,206 Grade 7 FA-3 Arabic Words.HTML
15/Mar/15  12:55 PM               239 gradient.html
05/Mar/15  03:15 PM                36 Hello.html
20/Apr/15  04:31 PM             2,348 HTML KNOWN CODES.html
15/Jan/16  02:02 PM               840 HTML Property Retriever bookmarks.html
01/Oct/16  02:50 PM             9,218 Image clue guessing.html
21/Nov/15  11:26 AM             3,622 Indian state names and their capitals.html
22/Jun/14  08:00 PM               137 Internet Explorer InPrivate Icon.htm
22/Apr/16  08:13 PM             1,831 JavaScript Executer.html
22/Jun/15  04:24 PM            21,367 Keyboard Tester.html
18/Dec/14  12:41 PM               440 Lines.html
20/Apr/15  03:41 PM             2,692 List of fonts.html
25/Dec/14  12:26 PM             1,467 LOCATION.html
28/Jun/15  12:44 PM             2,978 Mathematics tips and tricks.html
01/Oct/16  03:15 PM            11,274 Maths project.html
01/Oct/16  03:16 PM             2,074 Menu Bar Top.html
01/Oct/16  03:21 PM             7,549 MIDI Voice list.html
20/May/14  07:40 PM             2,755 NAME and details.html
13/Oct/16  03:07 PM               364 Operating System.html
22/Feb/15  08:15 PM               538 Picture Linking.html
01/Oct/16  03:35 PM             1,364 POPUP.html
20/Apr/15  04:47 PM             1,477 Questions.html
07/Aug/16  09:41 AM    <DIR>          RGB (html)
25/Feb/15  09:33 PM             3,851 RGB to Hex converter.html
22/Jun/15  05:38 PM             2,301 Riddles.html
01/Oct/16  03:38 PM             1,402 School friends' contact numbers.html
07/Aug/14  11:49 AM               491 Select.html
04/Jun/15  12:30 AM            13,958 S.St Project.html
27/May/14  04:24 PM             1,463 S.St.html
02/Sep/15  06:07 PM             6,195 SUSRI links.html
24/Nov/16  09:16 PM             4,297 Teachers.html
26/Oct/15  10:51 PM               760 TEMP folders.html
07/Aug/16  09:41 AM    <DIR>          Testers, editors and simulators
25/Nov/16  12:40 PM             6,636 TimeTable.html
17/Aug/15  03:59 PM               446 ToSearch.html
17/Aug/15  04:11 PM             4,338 Unusual characters.html
24/Nov/16  09:17 PM               956 Vanuvampet House TV Channels.html
05/Jan/15  05:56 PM               456 WEB-BROWSER TITLE TESTER (for designers).html
26/May/15  12:16 PM           172,480 Webpage not available.html
07/Feb/15  06:15 PM               727 What can I do now[sym question].html
21/Oct/16  08:23 PM             2,347 WhatsApp Formatting Converter.html
27/Nov/16  11:25 PM    <DIR>          Windows XP Style
27/Jul/15  11:46 AM             1,484 Window.html
25/Nov/16  01:07 PM            17,361 X 'n' O.SHTML
              76 File(s)      7,270,022 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  664,714,305,536 bytes free
```

For the difference, check the last two lines of both. For `DIR` it gives `80 Files; 6 Dirs` and for `DIR *1*` it gives `76 Files; 3 Dirs`.
I just want to know what `*1*` means. Is it something special? Most of the file/dir names do not contain **"1"**!
I also tried `DIR *2*`:

```
 Volume in drive C is Windows 10
 Volume Serial Number is 541B-FF75

 Directory of C:\Users\sreen\Desktop\All HTML files

30/Nov/16  04:08 PM               377 ButtonBeats paino player.html
29/Jan/15  10:31 PM               308 google.html
               2 File(s)            685 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  664,134,877,184 bytes free
```

My final question is: ***What is the meaning of `*1*` or `*2*`?***

I'd really appreciate any help. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*1*` and `*2*` are both wildcard matches on filenames.

But, it is likely that you have 8.3 short naming switched on. Behind the scenes there will be generated short names (these can be seen with `dir /x`. The generation often uses digits, and the wildcard checks both long and short names.

(Backwards compatibility is important, but has its own impact.)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about 8dot3 names being used with these wildcards. Google didn't help me there...
Thanks for your kind and instant help! ;-)